# How to have a Dynamic TableViewDataSource updates the table view?

Tags: ios, swift

I found the pattern used by the Google places IOS SDK to be clean and well designed. Basically they follow what is presented on the following apple presentation: [Advanced User interface with Collection view](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/232/) (It start slide 46).

This is what is implemented in their GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource.
It us up to the datasource to define the state of the tableview.
We link the tableview.

```
var googlePlacesDataSource = GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource()
tableView.dataSource = googlePlacesDataSource
tableView.delegate = googlePlacesDataSource
```

Then every time something change the event is binded to the datasource:

```
googlePlacesDataSource.sourceTextHasChanged("Newsearch")
```

The data source perform the query set the table view as loading and then display the result.

I would like to achieve this from my custom Source:

```
class JourneyTableViewDataSource:NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
   private var journeys:[JourneyHead]?{
        didSet{
         -> I want to trigger tableView.reloadData() when this list is populated... 
         -> How do I do that? I do not have a reference to tableView?
        }
   }

    override init(){
        super.init()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    ...
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your data source **shouldn't** know **anything** about your table view. This is the basic of this patter and it gives you a lot of power in terms of reusability.

For your purpose the best solution is to use the property closure:

```
var onJourneysUpdate: (() -> Void)?

private var journeys: [JourneyHead]? {
    didSet {
        onJourneysUpdate?()
    }
}
```

And in the point where you set your data source you can set whatever action you would like to execute after updating the datasource's array:

```
var googlePlacesDataSource = JourneyTableViewDataSource()
tableView.dataSource = googlePlacesDataSource
tableView.delegate = googlePlacesDataSource
googlePlacesDataSource.onJourneysUpdate = { [unowned self] in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is my plan B. :( The GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource does not do that. It manage some how to update or do something on its state that triggers the refresh of the table view... The google datasource implements a machine state and update the table view while uploading/getting the result/ No result.... How do they do that?

Comment: Did you check GMSAutocompleteTableDataSourceDelegate?
There is a method didUpdateAutocompletePredictionsForTableDataSource where people do usually put their tableview reloading code(as far as I saw after googling)

Comment: Yes I did and I use it like described in the google documentation. The method didUpdateAutocompletePredictionsForTableDataSource can be used to perform other actions but I do not need to use to update my table view. The only limitation they have is that the method that update the data source "sourceTextHasChanged" must be called from the main thread (for the exact reason that it updates the table view:))

Answer (score 0):

to update dynamic tableview, you have to add `reloadData`, `reloadData` updates datasource.

```
self.tableview.reloadData()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the datasource does not have a reference to the table view. So it cannot call the reloadData... this is exactly my issue :(